# how to add JS file in Node Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have added JavaScript file to my Node.js application and imported, but I cannot add the function from my JavaScript file to the `click` event of a button.

```js
import React from "react";

import styles from "./Homeapp.css";
import Homee from "./Homee";

const Home = ({ handleLogOut }) => {
  return (
    <div id="sidebar">
      <div class="toggel-btn" onClick="toggelsidebar()">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Contact Us</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: You want to add script .js?

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the *function* you want to call, and then pass the function and not a string to your JSX components `onClick` prop:

```
import { toggelsidebar } from "./someJsModule"
```

and

```
<div class="toggel-btn" onClick={toggelsidebar}>
```

This assumes that `someJsModule.js` exports `toggelsidebar` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

If you file is Homee please add extension.

import Homee from "./Homee.js"